# docker: could I run debian-based container on ubuntu host?

Tags: docker

Can I run container, based on debian:wheezy on ubuntu 14.04 host?
And if answer will be 'yes' - is it 'good way'? Or I should rebuild my image on same linux (for me ubuntu), as used on host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, that's one problem docker is to solve. No matter which distro you use, if it can run in docker container it can run on any linux server.